# How to create an exe out of ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I need to **create an .exe or find a way to run my project** in other computer witch i **don't have and i cant  install Visual Studio**. Is there a way to make this possible? Btw I'm using **Visual Studio 2013**. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There's no way of creating an EXE of an ASP.NET project (or at least one that would work with views, controllers etc). If you want an EXE, you should look at different project types.

Comment: As noted, there is no simple/single .exe option here. However, you will wind up with a web folder and all of the web pages in that folder. You can then transfer with a simple file copy or FTP or whatever and transfer that web site to a folder on a server that WILL require and be running a web server. So a web site requires all of the files, and they have to be correctly setup - and then you can have a web server dish out that "web site". there is no concept of a .exe file here - only that of a whole web site being consumed and dished out by a web server - and in most cases that means IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need visual studio to simply run an ASP.NET project, you can publish it to any machine that has the .NET runtime and a suitable web server.